# написать имя один раз

Tags: python, классы, list, opencv, print

```
import numpy as np
import face_recognition
import cv2
import os
from datetime import datetime
from tkinter import *
path = 'dataset'
images = []
classNames = []
myList = os.listdir(path)
print(myList)
for cls in myList:
    curImg = cv2.imread(f'{path}/{cls}')
    images.append(curImg)
    classNames.append(os.path.splitext(cls)[0])
print(classNames)
def findEncodings(images):
    encodeList = []
    for img in images:
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        encode = face_recognition.face_encodings(img)[0]
        encodeList.append(encode)
    return encodeList
def markAttendance(name):
    with open("Attendance.csv", "r+") as f:
        myDataList = f.readlines()
        nameList = []
        for line in myDataList:
            entry = line.split(',')
            nameList.append(entry[0])

        if name not in nameList:
            now = datetime.now()
            dtString = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
            f.writelines(f'\n{name}, {dtString}')

encodeListKnown = findEncodings(images)
print("Декодирование закончено")
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
for encodeFace, faceLoc in zip(encodeCurFrame, facesCurFrame):
    matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(encodeListKnown, encodeFace)
    faceDis = face_recognition.face_distance(encodeListKnown, encodeFace)
    matchIndex = np.argmin(faceDis)
    if matches[matchIndex]:
        name = classNames[matchIndex]
        print(name)
```

`print(name)` - на вот этом моменте оно будет писать много раз как сделать так что б писало один раз

Comment: Так там же цикл, вы хотите, чтобы `name`, которое вычислялось внутри цикла, просто тут же терялось? Или хотите накопить имена в список и вывести весь список в конце или что?

Comment: Как минимум не вызывать его в цикле много раз. от этого и повторения

Comment: Ну уменьшите табуляцию у `print(name)` так, чтобы эта конструкция начиналась  с той же позиции что и `for`, тогда один раз напечатается. Непонятно только зачем тогда всё что внутри цикла делается, оно просто так пропадёт.

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно выводить только первое совпадение, просто прерывайте цикл с помощью `break` при первом совпадении

```
for encodeFace, faceLoc in zip(encodeCurFrame, facesCurFrame):
    matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(encodeListKnown, encodeFace)
    faceDis = face_recognition.face_distance(encodeListKnown, encodeFace)
    matchIndex = np.argmin(faceDis)
    if matches[matchIndex]:
        name = classNames[matchIndex]
        print(name)
        break
```